# HTML Canvas displaying over my main content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to work a christmas Javascript overlay onto a website and the  tag I am using is displaying over the rest of my websites content.

```js
      window.onload = function(){
      //canvas init
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      
      //canvas dimensions
      var W = window.innerWidth;
      var H = window.innerHeight;
      canvas.width = W;
      canvas.height = H;
      
      //snowflake particles
      var mp = 25; //max particles
      var particles = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
      {
        particles.push({
          x: Math.random()*W, //x-coordinate
          y: Math.random()*H, //y-coordinate
          r: Math.random()*4+1, //radius
          d: Math.random()*mp //density
        })
      }
      
      //Lets draw the flakes
      function draw()
      {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
        
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
        ctx.beginPath();
        for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
        {
          var p = particles[i];
          ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
          ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        }
        ctx.fill();
        update();
      }
      
      //Function to move the snowflakes
      //angle will be an ongoing incremental flag. Sin and Cos functions will be applied to it to create vertical and horizontal movements of the flakes
      var angle = 0;
      function update()
      {
        angle += 0.01;
        for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
        {
          var p = particles[i];
          //Updating X and Y coordinates
          //We will add 1 to the cos function to prevent negative values which will lead flakes to move upwards
          //Every particle has its own density which can be used to make the downward movement different for each flake
          //Lets make it more random by adding in the radius
          p.y += Math.cos(angle+p.d) + 1 + p.r/2;
          p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;
          
          //Sending flakes back from the top when it exits
          //Lets make it a bit more organic and let flakes enter from the left and right also.
          if(p.x > W+5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H)
          {
            if(i%3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
            {
              particles[i] = {x: Math.random()*W, y: -10, r: p.r, d: p.d};
            }
            else
            {
              //If the flake is exitting from the right
              if(Math.sin(angle) > 0)
              {
                //Enter from the left
                particles[i] = {x: -5, y: Math.random()*H, r: p.r, d: p.d};
              }
              else
              {
                //Enter from the right
                particles[i] = {x: W+5, y: Math.random()*H, r: p.r, d: p.d};
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      
      //animation loop
      setInterval(draw, 33);
    }
```

```css
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    
    body {
      /*You can use any kind of background here.*/
      background: #6b92b9;
    }
    canvas {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
    <canvas id="canvas">
    <header> <a href = "/games/"><img id="headerimg" src="http://hosted-it.co.uk/img/logo-colour.svg" alt="Hosted-IT" height="150px" width="250px" /> </a></header>
    
    <nav class="navbar"><form method="get" action="/games/questions">
        <button type="onclick">Questions</button>
    </form> </nav>
    <body>
    
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    
    </body>
    </canvas>
```

If it helps, this is all inline script/html/css. It uses DJango templating to use a main html file to store the main formatting and then any other tweaks are made in the individual files. I was hoping if anyone could help me figure out why the canvas tag is overriding absolutely everything on the pages themselves ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a plunker, but for now you can try below css

```
canvas {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

change position to 'relative'. May be it will work. 
And in HTML close canvas tag on first line

```
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
   <header> <a href = "/games/"><img id="headerimg" src="http://hosted-it.co.uk/img/logo-colour.svg" alt="Hosted-IT" height="150px" width="250px" /></a></header>

    <nav class="navbar"><form method="get" action="/games/questions">
    <button type="onclick">Questions</button>
    </form> </nav>
    <body>

      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}

    </body>
```

Comment: I have tried this one already. I thought the absolute position may have been causing issues.

Comment: what if you close canvas tag in first line.

Comment: AHA!!!! Thank you. would you like to add it to the answers so I can mark it as the Answer?